# Retain Selection Criteria in Selectize

Tags: r, shiny, selectize.js

I'm using selectizeInput (with the multiple option) as part of my Shiny project, and I'm running into an issue where once I search for a criteria and select an item within the search bar, my search criteria is erased and I'm placed at the beginning of my dropdown menu. For example, say I type "27" into the search bar in the example below. There should be two items left in the dropdown. After I select one of the two, I would like it so that the filter is still present and leaves me with the other item available without having me to type "27" again.

I understand this is the normal behavior of selectize, but is there a way to keep the search criteria and the dropdown present after an item is selected?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- function(id){
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "test",
    label = NULL,
    choices = mtcars,
    options = list(placeholder = "None selected."),
    multiple = TRUE)
}

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While pickerInput is a solution, for those that want to stick with selectize, please consider the following:

1. Please download the script at the following GitHub link (I saved mine as preserve_search.js): https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/878#issuecomment-380382697
2. Please edit the below script to match your needs if you're planning to use the client-side version of Selectize:

```
addPreserveSearch <- function(x) {
  preserve_search <- htmlDependency("preserve_search", "1.0","location_of_your_script_folder",
                                script = "preserve_search.js")
  
  attachDependencies(x, c(htmlDependencies(x), list(preserve_search)))
}

library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  addPreserveSearch(selectizeInput(
    inputId = "test",
    label = NULL,
    choices = mtcars,
    options = list(plugins = list('preserve_search')),
    multiple = TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

3. If you're planning to use preserve_search on a server-side based selectize, please consider the following instead:

```
addPreserveSearch <- function(x) {
  preserve_search <- htmlDependency("preserve_search", "1.0","location_of_your_script_folder",
                                script = "preserve_search.js")
  
  attachDependencies(x, c(htmlDependencies(x), list(preserve_search)))
}


library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  
  addPreserveSearch(selectizeInput(
    inputId = "test",
    label = NULL,
    choices = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  updateSelectizeInput(
    session, inputId = "test",
    label = NULL, 
    choices = iris$Species,
    options = list(plugins = list('preserve_search')),
    server = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use pickerInput.  The following code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "pick", label = "Selected",
    choices = mtcars,
    multiple = TRUE,
    options = list( `live-search` = TRUE, `actions-box` = TRUE),
    choicesOpt = list(`style` = "btn-info",
                      `liveSearchPlaceholder`="Search" 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

gives this output when 27 is written in search box and 2 items are picked:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I need to clarify the situation: say I type "27" into the search bar. There should be two items left in the dropdown. After I select one of the two, I would like it so that the filter is still present and leaves me with the other item available without having me to type "27" again.

Comment: I have considered using pickerInput, but I would like to use selectize if possible.